# how to define an autoincrement id column in doctrine?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony 1.4 with doctrine as my ORM, I need to do one of two thing to get it working, and I don't know how to do it.

1. the id fields should not be bigint, just int or
2. When I define my table as follows:

   ```
   Table:
     columns:
       id:
       type: integer
       autoincrement: true
       primary: true
   ```

make the autoincrement work, because if I define my id like so it won't autoincrement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoincremented Id keys are automatically added by Doctrine if you do not specify one explicitly.

This should work as expected:

```
columns:
  nextfield: string
```

or:

```
columns:
  id:
    type: integer(2)
    autoincrement: true
    primary: true
  nextfield: string
```

Answer (score 0):

For the integer data type, check this out: http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/04-Schema-Files

For the auto-increment...

```
  primary: true
  autoincrement: true
```

... should be all you need.